# Lucene part:123 vs part 123 vs part123

Tags: lucene

I'm not too familiar with Lucene so my apologies if this isn't clear or I'm getting my terms/nomenclature mixed up.

So I have a requirement where a field containing text (example part:123) should be able to be found via the following:

- part:123
- part 123
- part123

Now my understanding of StandardAnalyzer is that it will break the word "part:123" into terms "part" and "123".

So with that, I'm able to search with part:123 or part 123, but because they're two different terms "part123" won't work.

It seems to me like I'd also need to get the indexer to add another term where both are combined, so it'd be "part", "123", "part123".

Is this the right way to accomplish this -- and does anyone know how I'd go about implementing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your understanding is correct: Using the `StandardAnalyzer` you will get two tokens `123` and `part` - and therefore you will probably not get the results you need if you search using `part123`. You can choose to pre-process your data, as you suggest. This is one possible way to get what you want. I suggest writing a basic proof-of-concept. Start [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_5_0/demo/overview-summary.html#overview.description) if you need guidance on how to implement this.  Also the tool `Luke` is great for exploring your indexed data and seeing how other analyzers work.